# iOS8 Set Popover Size In Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, size, ios8, popover

I'm trying to set the popover size of a view controller through the storyboard in iOS8. It should be noted that I'm using Obj-C, not swift, and Xcode6-Beta6.

I read the new documentation on popovers from Apple, and this post here was helpful:
[How to present popover properly in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635744/how-to-present-popover-properly-in-ios-8)

When I set the preferredContentSize of the view controller in code before presentation, it works fine and is the correct size. However, when I try to use the storyboard properties, "Popover:Use Explicit Size" and "Simulated Size:Freeform", they don't seem to affect the size of the popover like they did in iOS7 and earlier.

Is there any way to set the size of the popover through the storyboard in iOS8?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the Xcode6 Beta; I just got the Xcode6 GM version and all the popovers are the correct size.