# Showing View controller as a pop up- iOS8

Tags: ios, mobile

I have a series of buttons placed horizontally (say 5 in number) on top in my first View Controller. When I click on one of the five buttons , another view from a different controller (say Second View Controller ) should appear.

```
SecondViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

But this covers entire First View. Is there a way so that my second view appears as a pop up with the series of buttons still visible and working?

Comment: ios8 only or do you need to support previous versions too?  iPhone or iPad or both?

Comment: only iOS 8 and only iPhone

Comment: The you can use the new `present as popover` adaptive segue - See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635744/how-to-present-popover-properly-in-ios-8

Comment: But I am working on Objective C..not Swift

Comment: The language doesn't matter. You need to implement that method in order to get a popover style, not a fullscreen presentation.

Comment: Can you attach an image so we can visualize the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to show the viewcontroller without covering the whole screen try adding it as subview to the view controller.

```
  SecondViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];
controller.view.frame=CGRectMake(50,50,100,100);
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MJPopupViewController. Try this it will solve your problem. You can download it from here:-

https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController