# Pass value to View Controller's custom class?

Tags: ios, swift

Based on Xcode 7.2,Swift 2.

1. Create a SampleVC.swift in project. (Class SampleVC : UIViewController)
2. Create a View Controller in Storyboard.(Identity:"newView") In Interface Builder, within Identity Inspector, choose label class with SampleVC. Now I can modify "newView" within Class SampleVC.
3. Refer "newView" with `UIStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()` in code.Then `presentViewController()` show "newView".

I put step 3 in a button function, "newView" shows, everything is ok, but how can I pass some values to SampleVC?
Am I forced to use segue here? Because I think there must be a simple solution here.

Comment: If you are instantiating the VC then you can use its properties, methods etc however you like

Comment: No,I can't. I put an empty array in SampleVC, can't get this property outside. There is no "as SampleVC" in code, only IB knows I combined SampleVC with "newView", that's the problem.

Comment: Then put the `as SampleVC` in?

Comment: Yes! I find the same solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289173/pass-data-to-and-from-popover-in-swift. Thank you, Sami!