# Popup window in swift for tutorial view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

What is the easiest way to create popup window in swift?

For example I have a button called “Help”in the login screen and when I pressed Help button the tutorial screen will appear and blur the background.

I have tried NMPopUpView but didn’t luck to get it work.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is something I would like to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: I used same thing and it works....put some code

Comment: I tried this plugin and it is working but had issue when tapping the close button.

Comment: Try UIPresentationController

Comment: is there any alternative way to do it? Other than using NMPopUpView. Thanks.

Comment: you can check this.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635744/how-to-present-popover-properly-in-ios-8

Comment: I would simple create an UIView (Fullscreen for Background), with another UIView inside. So you are totally flexible with your Styling. You can animate everything you need (like it this example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i want a stylised popup then I will create a new Nib file and design it in there. Then when you want to show the popup you can load that NIB and animate it in, upon closing it you can animate it out.