# Does iOS supports OptionsMenu in navigation bar button like Android

Tags: ios, swift

I want to when I click on navigation bar button, it will expand a list option menu for me to handle each item in it. Does iOS supports it? And how to do it in swift?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can do so by creating your own view.

Answer (score 2):

Using popover that is a good candidate for you: [How to present popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635744/how-to-present-popover-properly-in-ios-8) or [display a popover in Swift](http://gracefullycoded.com/display-a-popover-in-swift/). Also, you can create custom UIView by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

1. create one view for pop-up and in view set you want(create class for this view)
2. set one button in navigation
3. create action for the navigation button
4. in button action set view is hide or show

   ```
   @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
       if (view.hidden){
           view.show = true
       }else{
           view.show = false
       }
   }
   ```