# is there a native options menu for swift ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, options-menu

I want to add a simple menu for my swift app.

An option menu or a sideBar.

I saw these tutorials

[Does iOS supports OptionsMenu in navigation bar button like Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326180/does-ios-supports-optionsmenu-in-navigation-bar-button-like-android)
===> how do I set 3 stips\dots image?

http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/  ==> is it considered harder to implement?

but is there a simple and native menu\sideBar for swift ios?

I could find it on Google.

Comment: Nope, the most common approach on iOS is to have a settings/options screen as the last screen on a `UITabBarController`. You can put extremely uncommon options in the actual iOS Settings app.

Comment: can you give an example? I'll see it that answer my needs

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

Comment: Would also recommend `SWRevealViewController` from Github for a navigation drawer similar to Android

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to implement if you are looking for.
https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

Comment: In swift I do not know, but the MMDrawerController can be implemented without any problem