# Can we handle the error "Cannot convert the value of type BOOL to expected argument UIiew"

Tags: ios, swift

I am tired of trying to PopOver the view controller and searched every where, tried myself also.This issue has again arrived and i am confused what to do next

```
func showPopover(base: UIView)
{
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Messaging", bundle: nil)
    if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PreferencesViewController") as?PreferencesViewController
    {
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

        if let pctrl = navController.popoverPresentationController 
        {
            pctrl.delegate = self

            pctrl.sourceView = base
            pctrl.sourceRect = base.bounds

            self.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this method in any one of the actions clicked from UIBarButtons

```
func optionChoosed(hello:Bool)
{
    if (hello)
    {
        self.showPopover(hello)
    }
}
```

it says **Cannot convert the value of type BOOL to expected argument UIiew**.. can we fix this or am i going wrong direction.

Comment: Here variable `hello` is `Bool` type. You need to pass `View` to method `showPopover`.

Comment: You need to use `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` methods to show the `popOver`.

Comment: can you edit my code and comment what are you trying to say.

Comment: Ok I will provide my code. do you want to show popover in `iPhone` or `iPad`?

Comment: I am using iPhone

Comment: replace  self.showPopover(hello) with  self.showPopover(self.view)

Comment: And also see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32175918/5801208 for popover

Comment: The error is quite clear - you have made a logical error while coding. Don't pass a `Bool` variable to the `showPopover` function, pass a reference to a `UIView`. You are using this `UIView` to be the source view and source rect. This obviously cannot be a `Bool`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SHNewStylesViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

var popover: UIPopoverPresentationController? = nil


//MARK: - View life cycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


//MARK: - IBActions

@IBAction func showPopover(sender: AnyObject) {
    let genderViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerTwoIdentifier") as! ViewControllerTwo
    genderViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    genderViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 400.0) // To change the popover size
    popover = genderViewController.popoverPresentationController!
    popover!.barButtonItem = sender as? UIBarButtonItem
    popover!.delegate = self
    presentViewController(genderViewController, animated: true, completion:nil)
}



//MARK: - Popover Presentation Controller Delegate methods

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}

}
```

In my case showPopover is a `IBAction` of my bar button item. You can you that code inside the `showPopover` method wherever you want.

Thanks:)